# How to check if a value in array is already at the database

Tags: magento-1.9, database, array

I have an array, and I need to check if one of his values are in my database. I tried with collections, but I wasn't successful. This is my array:

```
$ab = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [diffgrid] => Product1
                    [msdatarowOrder] => 0
                )

            [TIMESTAMP] => 
            [DEPARTAMENTO] =>                            
            [CATEGORIA] =>                                         
            [SUBCATEGORIA] =>                                     
            [FABRICANTE] => 
            [CODIGO] => 
            [DESCRICAO] =>
            [DESCRTEC] =>
            [PARTNUMBER] =>
            [EAN] =>
            [GARANTIA] =>
            [PESOKG] =>
            [PRECOREVENDA] =>
            [PRECOSEMST] =>
            [DATAVALIDADEPRECO] =>
            [DISPONIVEL] => 
            [URLFOTOPRODUTO] => 
            [ESTOQUE] => 
            [NCM] =>
            [LARGURA] =>
            [ALTURA] =>
            [PROFUNDIDADE] =>
            [ATIVO] => 
            [SUBSTTRIBUTARIA] => 
            [ORIGEMPRODUTO] =>
            [ESTOQUEDISPONIVEL] =>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [diffgrid] => Produtos2
                    [msdatarowOrder] => 1
                )

            [TIMESTAMP] =>
            [DEPARTAMENTO] =>
            [CATEGORIA] =>                                         
            [SUBCATEGORIA] =>                                      
            [FABRICANTE] => 
            [CODIGO] => 
            [DESCRICAO] =>
            [DESCRTEC] => 
            [PARTNUMBER] =>
            [EAN] =>
            [GARANTIA] =>
            [PESOKG] =>
            [PRECOREVENDA] => 
            [PRECOSEMST] => 
            [DATAVALIDADEPRECO] =>
            [DISPONIVEL] =>
            [URLFOTOPRODUTO] =>
            [ESTOQUE] =>
            [NCM] =>
            [LARGURA] =>
            [ALTURA] =>
            [PROFUNDIDADE] =>
            [ATIVO] =>
            [SUBSTTRIBUTARIA] =>
            [ORIGEMPRODUTO] =>
            [ESTOQUEDISPONIVEL] =>
        )
)
```

I need to check if the value of [CODIGO] is already in my table, at column "id_product". What would be the best way?

Model/Promotion.php:

```
class Novapc_Allnations_Model_Promotion extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Entity code.
     * Can be used as part of method name for entity processing
     */
    const ENTITY    = 'novapc_allnations_promotion';
    const CACHE_TAG = 'novapc_allnations_promotion';

    /**
     * Prefix of model events names
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'novapc_allnations_promotion';

    /**
     * Parameter name in event
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventObject = 'promotion';


    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('novapc_allnations/promotion');
    }

    protected function _beforeSave()
    {
        parent::_beforeSave();
        $now = Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate();
        if ($this->isObjectNew()) {
            $this->setCreatedAt($now);
        }
        $this->setUpdatedAt($now);
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _afterSave()
    {
        return parent::_afterSave();
    }


    public function getDefaultValues()
    {
        $values = array();
        $values['status'] = 1;
        return $values;
    }

}
```

Model/Resource/Promotion.php:

```
class Novapc_Allnations_Model_Resource_Promotion extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{

    /**
     * constructor
     *
     * @access public
     * @author .
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('novapc_allnations/promotion', 'entity_id');
    }
}
```

Model/Resource/Promotion/Collection.php:

```
class Novapc_Allnations_Model_Resource_Promotion_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{
    protected $_joinedFields = array();

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('novapc_allnations/promotion');
    }

    protected function _toOptionArray($valueField='entity_id', $labelField='name', $additional=array())
    {
        return parent::_toOptionArray($valueField, $labelField, $additional);
    }


    protected function _toOptionHash($valueField='entity_id', $labelField='name')
    {
        return parent::_toOptionHash($valueField, $labelField);
    }

    public function getSelectCountSql()
    {
        $countSelect = parent::getSelectCountSql();
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
        return $countSelect;
    }
}
```

And this is my table:

[image: table]

Comment: can you please add your database model from which you will get collection?

Comment: Done. (I guess? tell me if you need anything else, please)

Comment: what will you get in `CODIGO` and in `id_product` ?

Comment: 7 digits number

Comment: if its unique value then you can use `addFieldToFilter()` function

Comment: Yes, its unique. I tried that, but I wasn't successful. I'm new to magento (1 month working with it) and some of the functionalities are still confusing to me. Could you just give me a brief explanation of how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($ab as $x){
     if($x['CODIGO'] != NULL){
         $model = Mage::getModel('novapc_allnations/promotion')->addFieldToFilter('id_product', $x['CODIGO']);
         var_dump($model->getData());
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you to get record from DB.

Comment: is it working ???

Comment: Sorry for taking too long. Yes, it worked, thank you

Comment: Glad that it worked for you